# How I can change the value of a commerce product field after Completion process?

Tags: commerce

I want to change the value of one of my product custom fields when "Checkout completion". I created that custom field myself, with machine name `field_prodstat`.

How I can do that with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: I'm assuming this question is about D7.

Create a custom rule (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) like so:

- Rules Event: checkout completion event.
- Rules Condition: entity has field, for the field with machine name "`field_prodstat`" (which will make that field available as a token you can select in subsequent Rules Events and/or Rules Actions).
- Rules Action: set a data value, for the field with machine name "`field_prodstat`".

#### Update

Below is an attempt to also address your comment below this answer, the relevant part of that comment is like so:

> I have a content type called "Appointment". When that appointment status = "Accepted Pending Payment" I created a rule to build a new product for that "appointment". So now I have a product related to that appointment. I just want to update "Appointment" status to "Paid" when his product appear in an order with status = invoiced. I don't know if you have any other proposal to do that.

That comment starts revealing your real question, which is pretty different from your original question. To answer your *real* question is not something that can be explained in just a few phrases. I suggest you have a look at the video tutorial about [Removing Items From the Cart Using Rules](https://vimeo.com/35719774) which demonstrates a scenario which is pretty similar to what you're asking for (in your extra comment). Here is part of what is shown in that video (quote is from that link):

> - Create a rule that loops through all the line items when the order is about to be saved. Have it call a component (rules subroutine) for each line item to see if that line item should be removed.
> - Create the component that does the work. It needs to take two arguments (line item and the order-about-to-be-saved).

To make this also work for your case, I think you'd be close if you only replace the last Rules Action in the used Rules Component by a Rules Action that applies the update you're asking for in your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  -What I should put in : Data selector (Rules Condition ) ?

Comment: @MediaWEB what are the possible options you can select?

Comment: commerce-order ////
commerce-order:owner:... ////
commerce-order:commerce-line-items:...

Comment: My turn to ask questions: your question is about "***one of my product ...***" (custom fields). And your previous comment seems to indicate (1 or more) "***line items***" (which IMO is not a surprise, since at checkout time you're processing a cart, containing line items). So what exactly is it that you want to change the value for? Just a guess, maybe you do have a specific SKU in mind of some line items for which you want to change the value of your field_prodstat field? Or is it something completely different? Please improve your question to clarify all this.

Comment: Look , I have a content type called "Appointment" , When that appointment status = "Accepted Pending Payment" I created a rule to build a new product for that "appointment" , so now I have a product related to that appointment , I just want to update "Appointment" status to "Paid" when his product appear in an order with status = invoiced , I am sorry for my bad english !! I don't know if you have any other proposal to do that

Comment: @MediaWEB : wow, your last comment starts revealing your real question, which is pretty different from your original question. I suggest you integrate your comments below my answer into your original question. So that at least you have a more accurate question. However, to answer your real   question is not something that can be done in just a few phrases. So I wouldn't be surprised if your (real) question would be put on hold as "too broad". Not sure how to move forward on this question. PS: your english is fine (even more then good enough).

Comment: Oh Thanks for that , I was scared how I could explain my issue here !! if you can give me your email or your skype id which I can be in touch with you

Comment: How can we do the same in Drupal 8 without using rule - change the value of one of product custom fields when "Checkout completion".
http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21checkout%21commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_complete/7